# How to declare a scope based on embedded model attributes with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, mongoid

I have a `User` model which embeds a `Profile`:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User
  embeds_one :profile
end

# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile
  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :profile
  field :age, type: integer
end
```

Now I want to declare a scope in `User` which can list out all users whose `profile.age` is `> 18`.

Comment: Do u want to fetch only associated B's of A in scope or all ?

Comment: First thing you written embeds_one which means for A there will be only one B, So why  age> 18 ????  secondly: if you want fetch all b regardless of A's then dont use embeds_one

Comment: Let User is A and Profile is B and Profile model contains age field
And I want to fetch all the users whose age is greater than 18

Comment: @manojchowdary27 why don't you change the example code to `class User ; embeds_one :profile ; end`? It's much easier to reason about actual classes.

Comment: Sorry @stefan. I have modified it .Now take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query attributes of embedded documents via:

```
User.where(:'profile.age'.gt => 18)
```

or as a scope:

```
class User
  embeds_one :profile

  scope :adults, -> { where(:'profile.age'.gt => 18) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @stefan this works for me.I tried this earlier.I think i made a syntax error at  that time.Thanks you saved lot of time for me.

Comment: can u please upvote my question too.and thank again for ur answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use *embeds* you can access only associated B objects of A. So, your need i.e all B where age>x doesn't work. So, go for *has_one* and *belongs_to*

**A.rb**

```
class A
  has_one :b
  scope :adults, -> { Bar.adults }
end
```

**B.rb**

```
class B
 field :age ,type:integer
 belongs_to :a
 scope :adults, -> { where(:age.gt=> 18)}
end
```

Comment: Sorry It is not possible to change association  to has_one.Because Both the models are using single mongo collection.So I should use only embeds_one association.
Thanks a lot for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

This should save your day -))

```
Class B    
 field :age, type:integer
 scope :adults,  -> { where(:age.gt => 18) }  
end

class A
  embed_one :b
  def embed_adults
    b.adults
  end   
end
```

https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#scoping

Comment: I tried it , but it is showing undefined method or variable b for class A

Comment: And B.all is nil. It may be  because there is only one collection A and it embeds B.There is no such collection B in mongodb